# How to get status bar height in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How do I get the status bar height?

[image]

Answer (score 118, accepted):

```
var height = MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding.top;
```

**Note**: This will only work on mobile devices because other platforms don't have a dedicated status bar and it will returns `0.0` for them.

Comment: returns 0.0 on my mobile too

Comment: return `0.0` on android device

Comment: @omega_mi What `MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top` returns?

Comment: @iDecode both padding.top & viewPadding.top return 0.0

Comment: @omega_mi it will return a different value depending on the device. For example the iPhone 14 has a space for the camera at the top. viewPadding will account for this.

Answer (score 1):

IDK why but in some cases we lose the MediaQuery data on the leafs of our WidgetTree.
Try to get the MediaQuery using the same context of your Scaffold and it should work

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT :** `window` is now deprecated (and seem to have been deprecated even before this answer was initially posted ) so this answer is invalid after Flutter 3.7.0

`MediaQuery` is cool, but if you don't have access to a `BuildContext` you can use `window.viewPadding.top` directly, where `window` comes from `dart:ui`:

```dart
import 'dart:ui';

final statusBarHeight = window.viewPadding.top;
```

**Note:** As stated in the [Dart documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/FlutterView/viewPadding.html), this can include other things than the status bar so be careful when using these APIs

Comment: Unfortunately, window deprecated(

Answer (score -6):

Hope it will help you, just add latest  [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get)  package in your application and import following library in your code.

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
```

**Status Bar Height**

To get status bar height use following a bit code:

```
Get.statusBarHeight;
```

**Bottom Bar Height**

To get bottom bar height use following a bit code:

```
Get.bottomBarHeight;
```

**Screen Height**

To get screen height use following a bit code:

```
Get.height;
```

**Screen Width**

To get screen width use following a bit code:

```
Get.width;
```

Also you can use `SafeArea()` widget to ignore overlays to use this just wrap your widget with this.

Comment: I have noticed Get. statusBarHeight will NOT return the same as MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding.top. Rather it returns a computed calculation of status bar height + AppBar height (off by a few pixels BTW)

Comment: I would not recommend adding a full-blown framework like GetX just for the sake of finding just the statusbar height.

Comment: This is just for those who are using getx in their code for other I mentioned in my answer that also you may use safearea and mediaquery.